# Return single row single value result set of Execute SQL task as an input to another execute SQL task in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, ssis, execute-sql-task

I need to pass the single value result of an execute SQL task as the input to another. I need to have to separate tasks since I need 2 different connections. (both SQL Server, but different environments)

Comment: You need a lot of things. What is your question ? What have you done so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok simple. First create a variable for the value you want to pass.

Then in your execute sql task, write the query that brings up that value. Make sure to set the result set to single row.

Then go to the variables tab and add your new variable in there.

Once that's done, go to your next task, and in the parameters section add your variable there. I'm assuming both tasks are sql tasks.

Then in the query for the second task use a ? Symbol to represent the variable.

Let me know if that makes sense. I can post screenshots tonight.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I'm doing it in a foreach loop container using Object variable. The challenge I am facing now is the data type mismatch. My first and second, both execute SQL tasks are parameterised. The input for first is nvarchar variable and the output is a datetime field (which is the input for second execute SQL task) and returns the error "An error occurred while extracting the result into a variable of type (DBTYPE_DBTIMESTAMP)"

Comment: Nvm, fixed it by casting :)

Answer (score 3):

Your question can be divided into 2 parts:

1. **Passing the Execute SQL Task result into a variable**: You can refer to the following articles to learn more about how to use ResultSets to store an Execute SQL Task result into SSIS variables:

   - [SSIS Basics: Using the Execute SQL Task to Generate Result Sets](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-execute-sql-task-to-generate-result-sets/)
   - [How do I capture the single row value from Execute SQL Task that uses an expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167562/how-do-i-capture-the-single-row-value-from-execute-sql-task-that-uses-an-express)
   - [Map Result Sets to Variables in an Execute SQL Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/map-result-sets-to-variables-in-an-execute-sql-task?view=sql-server-2014)
2. **Passing the variable as parameter for another Execute SQL Task**: You can refer to the following articles to learn more about passing parameters to Execute SQL Task:

   - [Passing Variables to and from an SSIS task](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/passing-variables-to-and-from-an-ssis-task/)
   - [How to pass variable as a parameter in Execute SQL Task SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610491/how-to-pass-variable-as-a-parameter-in-execute-sql-task-ssis)
   - [Map Query Parameters to Variables in an Execute SQL Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/map-query-parameters-to-variables-in-an-execute-sql-task?view=sql-server-2014)